# RESTful web server library for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, json, cocoa, rest

I am trying to create a Rest web service running on iPhone; I've done  my initial research and found 
CocoaHttpServer and TouchCode json parser, is there any library / sample code which binds these together into a Rest endpoint?

If it does not exist, how do I go about writing one? Any reference to some kind of design document etc. will really help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using CocoaHTTPServer and the iOS builtin JSON libraray to have a RESTful service in iVocabulary. First I wrote a lengthy Connection class (the core for handling requests in CocoaHTTPServer) myself. But parsing the URL was kind of complicated.

So I wrote a more generic Connection class that routes HTTP requests to different blocks for different URLs and different HTTP methods. The URL can contain parameters (with : as prefix), that get parsed. That's not a generic REST service per se, but I added (for example) a block for the url "/rest/:entityname" that fetches all Core Data objects of the given entity.

You can find that router implementation in my fork of CocoaHTTPServer on github: https://github.com/chbeer/CocoaHTTPServer

Another router implementation: https://github.com/mattstevens/RoutingHTTPServer

Comment: My extension works the same. But I added it to my fork of CocoaHTTPServer as an external extension.

Answer (score -1):

Check RestKit for working with Restful web services.

http://restkit.org/

Comment: @nielsbot : exactly , I looked into RestKit, it does not provide any "server" api's, it can only consume..

Answer (score -2):

I recommend [RestKit](http://restkit.org), I have used for over a year now and love it. However I recently learned about [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) from some colleagues that claim it's very lightweight and thus prefer it as an alternative to RestKit, so I am giving it a try soon.